# Why do I have three ip v6 adresses

Tags: networking

The output of ifconfig is the following

```
wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.178.43  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
    inet6 xxxx::xxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 yyyy::yyyy  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 zzzz::zzzz  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 10043888  bytes 13826164373 (13.8 GB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 3274278  bytes 382981422 (382.9 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Why does one interface need/have three ip v6 addresses?

Comment: see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/141397/why-do-i-get-multiple-global-ipv6-addresses-listed-in-ifconfig

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 differs from IPv4 not only in longer addresses, but also in address scopes for these addresses.

This means that every IPv6 address has a so-called scope. The scope is the part of a network in which the associated address is recognized as valid and routed.

You have 2 global scope and one link scope.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response.
But why would I need two global ones?

Comment: Because you typically have one fixed one, that is primarily used for incoming connections, and temporary addresses used for outgoing connections. The ones used for outgoing connections changes every few hours.

Comment: I dont see your ip's, may be it's advertised by the router along with the global prefix